# pl/sql. after each statement does not a variable defined before the before statement clause when writing a compound trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table Uspev on schema MARSEL, which contains columns student(a student's ID), predmet(a subject's ID), ocenka(a mark) and data(an exam date). I need to write a compound trigger that prohibits a student from sitting exams (does not care which one, just the fact of sitting) more than two exams a day. There was an example of a trigger provided by proffessor, but it resulted in "mutating-table" error.
As for my code, there are variables declared before the before statement, namely an array of records and a counter. While a counter is not highlighted with red, the array used in SELECT COUNT(*) is. I wrote it according to the manual 'https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle//oracle-database/21/lnpls/database-pl-sql-language-reference.pdf', but it does not seem to work. Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MARSEL.STUD_USPEV
    FOR UPDATE OF DATA ON MARSEL.USPEV
    COMPOUND TRIGGER
    TYPE r_student_exam_date_type IS RECORD (  //a record type to hold a student ID
        stud        MARSEL.USPEV.STUDENT%TYPE, //and their exam date
        exam_date   MARSEL.USPEV.DATA%TYPE
    ); 
    TYPE t_student_exam_date_type IS TABLE OF r_student_exam_date_type //array type containing the records
        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    t_student_exam_date     t_student_exam_date_type; //the array declaration
    counter number;        //the counter will count how many exams a student have sat during a day being inserted
    
    BEFORE STATEMENT IS 
        BEGIN
            SELECT r_student_exam_date_type  // inserting all rows into the array
            BULK COLLECT INTO t_student_exam_date 
            FROM MARSEL.USPEV;
    END BEFORE STATEMENT;
    
    AFTER EACH ROW IS
        BEGIN
            counter := 0;
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter  //counting existing dates with the same student ID as the one being inserted
            FROM t_student_exam_date  //HIGHLIGHTED AS UNDEFINED
            WHERE stud = :NEW.student AND exam_date = :NEW.data;
            IF (counter > 1) 
                THEN Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'a student cannot sit more than two exams a day');
            END IF;
    END AFTER EACH ROW;
END STUD_USPEV;
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Comments begin with `--` not `//`.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `declare` keyword between `compound trigger` and the first `type`. Also you can't just query an associative array (`table of x index by y`) as if it was a database table.

Comment: Just to comment on coding style, PL/SQL conditional expressions are terminated by the `then` keyword and therefore not enclosed in brackets. Programming languages tend to use one or the other, not both. Also there's no need to uppercase keywords and arbitrary object names - it's not Fortran.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a locally-declared collection type in a SQL query; even if you did `TABLE(t_student_exam_data)` and tool away the `INDEX BY` clause, you'd get ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item. The collection type would need to be created at schema level or be declared in a package specification for it to be usable in a query.

You can loop over the collection instead, and increment your counter for each matching record:

```
    AFTER EACH ROW IS
        BEGIN
            counter := 0;
            FOR i IN 1..t_student_exam_date.count
            LOOP
                IF t_student_exam_date(i).stud = :NEW.student
                    AND t_student_exam_date(i).exam_date = :NEW.data
                THEN
                    counter := counter + 1;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;

            IF counter > 1
            THEN
                Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'a student cannot sit more than two exams a day');
            END IF;
    END AFTER EACH ROW;
```

Your bulk-collect was also wrong, but maybe changed incorrectly while posting; and the comments you added were illegal. And you need the trigger to be `FOR INSERT OR UPDATE` With those changed it now works.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Q_HcDRW)

You might want to look at edge cases like updating a row to the same date...